# Show selected records in Smarty

Tags: php, database, arrays, smarty

My selected query from mysql is :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
```

and then I trying to fetch records with `mysql_fetch_object` or `mysql_fetch_array` :

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object($query);
```

then I pass this variable to Smarty :

```
$smarty->assign('record',$result);
```

in my smarty tpl file my code is :

```
<table>
{foreach $record as $item}
    <tr>
        <td>{$item.title}</td>
        <td>{$item.visit}</td>
        <td>{$item.date}</td>
        <td>{$item.date}</td>
        <td>{$item.date}</td>
        <td>{$item.date}</td>
        <td>{$item.date}</td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

but after I run my code I will get cluttered characters.
What's the problem ?

UPDATE:

result screen shot
[image: result screen shot]

Comment: What is the output, your code seems to be correct

Comment: @m4t1t0 for sample numbers or � character, I have 2 records in my table  but in result I will get about 12 rows ! (in my table i have 10  columns)

Comment: if you print_r($result); what do you get?

Comment: does same thing happens when you use mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_object?

Comment: do you really just do `$result = mysql_fetch_object($query);` ? If yes, you only have a single object instead of an object array. This could cause the strange output

Answer (score -1):

look this

```
    {foreach from=$record as $item}
    <tr>
        <td>{$item.title}</td>
        <td>{$item.visit}</td>
        <td>{$item.date}</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: You're using smarty 2.x syntax, he was using smarty 3.x syntax.